# Which is the best serial port library that can be used on Linux

Tags: java, serial-port, rxtx

I want to know the best library to use for serial port communication in Java. I have tried rxtx 1.4 which uses comm.jar, but I ran into some issues. When I test the installation using SampleDemo the port is opened but when I type characters to be sent through the port it is not writing to the port, leading to the result that I do not get any response back.

Is there any way to check if the writing is happening or not? I think there is some problem with the library so suggest me some nice ideas to get over it!!

Comment: Get latest version of [RXTX](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Download) library: rxtx 2.1-7r2 (stable)